# unicode characters not showing correctly on one server (Azure)

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, unicode

this problem is driving me nuts. I have a test server and a live server. The test server is showing unicode characters retrieved from an Azure sql database correctly. While the live server running identical code accessing the same data is not showing them correctly.

The data in the database is:
Hallo ich heiße Pokémon! Ich würde gerne mal mit einem anderen Kämpfe!

The test servers shows 
    Hallo ich heiße Pokémon! Ich würde etc...

The live server, which is an Azure web  service shows 
    Hallo ich hei�e Pok�mon! Ich w�rde gerne mal mit einem anderen K�mpfe

Same PHP code, Same database, Same browser, same db connection string,
different web servers, different results.

I do know Azure is running PHP 5.6 and the test server is running PHP 5.3
They are using sqlsrv_connect
The data field is type  varchar.

I tried using "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"  in the connection but this made no difference to the Azure server and screwed up the result on the test server.

I am out of ideas and leads.

Comment: Make sure table definitions are the same, i.e. column types and collations

Comment: Open your browser's web inspector while you make the request in both live and test; ensure that character encoding returned by the server is the same.

Answer (score 0):

As your application runs on Azure App Service, you could try the following options:

- Set this in your PHP page:

  ```
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  ```
- Create a file named `.user.ini` to `/wwwroot` directory with the following content:

  ```
  default_charset = "UTF-8"
  ```
- Set the `responseEncoding` attribute of the [globalization element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.71).aspx) in the `web.config` file:

  ```
  <configuration>
      <system.web>
          <globalization 
              requestEncoding="utf-8"
              responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
      </system.web>
  </configuration>
  ```

**More on this:** [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Checking my phpinfo shows the default char set is already utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I swear I tried this before, but this turns out to be the answer

```
"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"
```

added to the connection string, and

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

in the web page.